# Find the exact string with grep

Tags: grep

by way of example, I've a big text file with many email address, using bash I need search/verify that an email exists (or no). Should be use (only) the "anchors"?

```
grep '^user1@example.com' text_file
```

or there're better ways? I need create a bash script and I'd like be safe.

Comment: Is the email the only word on a line?

Comment: indeed: the file has this format: user1@example.com example.com/user1

Comment: In that case, I'd use `grep -q '^user1@example\.com\>'` -- with a line anchor at the start, and an end-of-word anchor at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match

Answer (score 26):

See the `-F` (fixed string, as opposed to regular expression) and `-x` (exact: match the whole line) options.

```
grep -Fx user1@example.com text_file
```

would be the equivalent of:

```
grep '^user1@example\.com$' text_file
```

(remember that `.` is a regular expression operator that matches any character).

Use the `-q` option if you only want to check if there's such a line:

```
grep -Fxq user1@example.com text_file &&
  echo yes, that address is in that file.
```

If the line to search and the file name are variable:

```
grep -Fxqe "$email" < "$file"
```

Or

```
grep -Fxq -- "$email" < "$file"
```

You don't want:

`grep -Fxq "$email" "$file"`

as that would cause problems if `$email` or `$file` started with `-`.

If the file is sorted (in your current locale, preferably `C`), you can possibly speed things up by using `comm` instead of `grep`:

```
printf '%s\n' user1@example.com | comm -12 - text_file
```

The advantage will become more obvious when you have several email addresses to check (for instance in another sorted file):

```
comm -12 text_file emails_to_check
```

would be faster than:

```
grep -Fxf emails_to_check text_file
```

Comment: AFAIK, `grep -Fxq -- "$email" "$file"` also works.

Comment: stephane, why did you switch from a file input (handled by grep) to stdin using the `<` redirector? are there any advantages?

Comment: @umläute and vinc17. As I said, it's to cover for filenames starting with `-`. even `grep -- "$email" "$file"` would be a problem for a file called `-` (which `grep` treats specially as meaning _stdin_)

Answer (score 6):

To be as efficient as possible, you want to stop after the first match is found. If you have GNU `grep`, you can do this:

```
grep -m 1 '^user1@example\.com$' your_file
```

If you don't, you can use Perl:

```
perl -nlE 'say and last if $_ eq q{user1@example.com}' your_file
```

Comment: `-m` is GNU specific. Use the POSIX `-q` if you want to efficiently check that there's such a line.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of email checks there. One of those is:

```
grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b" text_file
```

To elaborate my answer.

You are using the `^` anchor which indicates the start of the string. This won't match if an email address is somewhere in between a long string.

Comment: Thanks. That's is a generic grep options to "extract" all email address inside a file. I need searching for one by one email address using read EMAIL then using grep to check it.

Answer (score 2):

your `grep` command will match everything that starts with `^user1@example.com`, including the email address itself, but also `user1@example.com.spammer.com`. since `.` is a special character in regular expressions that matches any key, you should escape it as `\.`

assuming that your textfile contains one address per line, use:

```
EMAIL=user1@example\\.com
egrep "^${EMAIL}$" text_file
```

the trailing `$` will make sure that the line ends after the email-address.
i'm also using double-quotes `"`, as these allow to use variables (unlike single-quotes `'`)

Comment: That also matches `user1@example-com`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you're of course right; updated the answer.

Comment: @umläute You need to double the backslash. But it's better to use `-Fx`.

Comment: @vinc17, doh; bash escaping; anyhow, yes i agree that it is better to use `-Fx` but that's stephane's answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Considering general literal/exact string match:

```
grep -w "search_word" <file>  >  output.txt

#\b shows boundaries over here.
```

or,

```
 grep  "\bsearch_word\b"  <file>  >  output.txt
```